# SQL syntax error when completing query on a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search a video database for information about them. everything is in one page. There are no external form posting into this one, its located on this page.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("videos", $connection) or die (mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";

if (isset($_POST['search'])){
  $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

  $sql .= "WHERE name LIKE '{$search_term}'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<html>
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="display_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="search_box" placeholder="Search..."/>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
</form>
<table style="width:70%; cellpadding:5 cellspace:6">

<tr>
  <td><strong>Film ID</strong></td>
  <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
  </tr>


<?php } ?>

</table>
</html>
```

But I get the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 'Walking'' at line 1
```

walking is just the search term.

Answer (score 4):

You should `echo $query` out before you actually run it, copy the output and run it in a mysql session directly.  I'm guessing it will tell you that you need a space before the `"WHERE"` keyword.

Oh, and `mysql_query` is deprecated and very dangerous - look at `PDO or mysqli` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, this did not help fix the problem, but certainly gave some good advice, ill research Mysqli because it sounds similar to MySql, still need to resolve this problem for now though

Comment: If that's not the current error, it will be soon :) ... I think the other problem may be the '{$search_term}' .. Try LIKE "'" . $search_term . "'"; instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is the concatination of your strings. The result will be `SELECT * FROM videosWHERE name LIKE '{$search_term}'`;

Add a space before `WHERE` and the error should gone.

You should not longer use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements to prevent sql-injection.

Answer (score 1):

SIMPLY add space beore your WHERE clause, like this:

```
$sql .= " WHERE name LIKE '{$search_term}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a space before `WHERE`!

```
$sql .= " WHERE name LIKE '{$search_term}'";
```

Comment: wow, these guys are quick - I need to brush up on my touch typing! :)

Comment: I think you was the first, so ill mark yours as the answer, thanks mate

Comment: Oli, TBH I think @Ram pipped me and he added value with pointing you to use the mysqli/pdo functions

Comment: Im seriously not sure, The page crashed because of all the comments, so if they was first reply here, and ill happily change it to them. Otherwise you can keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$sql .= "WHERE name LIKE '{$search_term}'";
```

No space between `videos and where`

You need to add space

```
$sql .= " WHERE name LIKE '{$search_term}'"; 
         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addslashes()` function rather then use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. The quote string with slashes so, it will be very useful to you when you are adding any apostrophe in your field.

I have set php code with above detail, replace with your PHP code section and check.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("videos", $connection) or die (mysql_error());

//Select statement for query

$sql = " SELECT * FROM videos ";
//Check for request
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
   //Prepare request value for query
   $search_term = addslashes($_POST['search_box']);

   //Where statement
  $sql .= " WHERE name LIKE '" . $search_term . "' ";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I have remove some bug and set `addslashes()`. Please try this.

And I suggest you, instead of using the old mysql* functions, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and write parameterized queries.

Let me know if require any help from me regarding this.

Comment: Where do I enter the data, its just a blank page.

Comment: Do not use addslashes, It's vulnerable http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: @Oliver Ketley: did you mean that there is nothing to display after use given code?

Comment: Think ill research the link provided, my problem has been solved, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Pleasure Oliver! Feel free to contact us anytime, always happy to help. :)